# Apns notification error: 'ConnectionError' and Failed to Connect, check your firewall settings

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working with PushSharp 4.0.10  and using .p12 certificate i get this error **[*"Apns notification error: 'ConnectionError'"*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqLIn.png)** and InnerException is ***"Failed to Connect, check your firewall settings"***.is anyone knows how to solve this error.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

```
    var certificate = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/jetzydev.p12"));
    var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, certificate, "12345");

    var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);
    var fbs = new FeedbackService(config);

    apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (Notification, aggregateEx) =>
    {
        aggregateEx.Handle(ex =>
        {
            if (ex is ApnsNotificationException)
            {
                var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;
                var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;
            }

            return true;
        });
    };

    apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (Notification) =>
    {
        Response.Write("done");
        //  logger.Debug("Apple Notification Sent!");                  
    };

    // Start the broker
    apnsBroker.Start();


    try
    {
        apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification()
        {
            DeviceToken="---------------------------------------",
            Payload = JObject.Parse("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"body\": \"This is message from local host 1\",\"title\": \"title\"},\"sound\":\"beep.wav\"}}")
        });
        apnsBroker.Stop();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
        //logger.Debug(" SendPushNotificationToApple :- " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: its in iOS or android or else

Comment: it might be that the ISP has blocked port 2195 (and 2196).Open these ports